# Docker Rancher - Permission Denied when using docker from WSL

Tags: docker, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rancher

I have installed Docker Rancher on Windows 10 with dockerd option and WSL on true for my current WSL distribution (Ubuntu).
When i try to use docker in WSL2, I had the following error:

```
fpapi@xxx:~$ docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

The command works fine in the cmd shell.

Which kind of permission I'm missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue is that Docker Rancher installer do not create the `docker` group.
Use the following commands:

```
sudo addgroup --system docker
sudo adduser $USER docker
newgrp docker
# And something needs to be done so $USER always runs in group `docker` on the `Ubuntu` WSL
sudo chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock
sudo chmod g+w /var/run/docker.sock
```

thanks to https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/1156#issuecomment-1017042882

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).